# AWS Athena: Get list of tables & columns efficiently

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am creating a Grafana dashboard to integrate with AWS Athena.

In doing so, I would like users to be able to select across all available columns in my database for a specific device. My tables are structured as `deviceid_signalgroupname` with signals in columns.

I'm currently testing below query, which works:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(table_name, '.', column_name) AS table_column
FROM 
    information_schema.columns 
WHERE 
    table_name LIKE '%${device:csv}%'
    AND column_name NOT IN ('date_created', 't')
ORDER BY 
    table_name, 
    ordinal_position;
```

However, it is very slow and takes 8-10 seconds to run. I have around 400 tables each with around 5-10 columns. For this query I'm trying to extract around 50 tables, each with around 5 columns. I would expect this to be possible to do in a smarter way that is more efficient?

Below is an example of the query results in Athena:

[image]

Below is the output when doing an `explain analyze` on the above query:

```
Query Plan
Queued: 618.32us, Analysis: 2.13ms, Planning: 2.51s, Execution: 22.13s
Fragment 1 [SINGLE]
    CPU: 1.53ms, Scheduled: 1.56ms, Blocked 1.62m (Input: 19.49s, Output: 0.00ns), Input: 1554 rows (142.90kB), Data Scanned: 0B; per task: avg.: 1554.00 std.dev.: 0.00, Output: 1554 rows (83.05kB)
    Output layout: [concat]
    Output partitioning: SINGLE []
    Project[projectLocality = LOCAL]
    │   Layout: [concat:varchar]
    │   CPU: 0.00ns (0.00%), Scheduled: 0.00ns (0.00%), Blocked: 0.00ns (0.00%), Output: 1554 rows (83.05kB)
    │   Input avg.: 388.50 rows, Input std.dev.: 173.21%
    └─ LocalExchange[partitioning = ROUND_ROBIN]
       │   Layout: [ordinal_position:bigint, concat:varchar, table_name:varchar]
       │   CPU: 0.00ns (0.00%), Scheduled: 0.00ns (0.00%), Blocked: 1.30m (40.00%), Output: 1554 rows (142.90kB)
       │   Input avg.: 1554.00 rows, Input std.dev.: 0.00%
       └─ RemoteMerge[sourceFragmentIds = [2]]
              Layout: [ordinal_position:bigint, concat:varchar, table_name:varchar]
              CPU: 1.00ms (0.28%), Scheduled: 1.00ms (0.01%), Blocked: 19.49s (10.00%), Output: 1554 rows (142.90kB)
              Input avg.: 1554.00 rows, Input std.dev.: 0.00%

Fragment 2 [ROUND_ROBIN]
    CPU: 39.00ms, Scheduled: 41.26ms, Blocked 1.62m (Input: 1.30m, Output: 0.00ns), Input: 1554 rows (142.90kB), Data Scanned: 0B; per task: avg.: 1554.00 std.dev.: 0.00, Output: 1554 rows (142.90kB)
    Output layout: [ordinal_position, concat, table_name]
    Output partitioning: SINGLE []
    LocalMerge[orderBy = [table_name ASC NULLS LAST, ordinal_position ASC NULLS LAST]]
    │   Layout: [ordinal_position:bigint, concat:varchar, table_name:varchar]
    │   CPU: 4.00ms (1.10%), Scheduled: 4.00ms (0.02%), Blocked: 19.49s (10.00%), Output: 1554 rows (142.90kB)
    │   Input avg.: 388.50 rows, Input std.dev.: 34.28%
    └─ PartialSort[orderBy = [table_name ASC NULLS LAST, ordinal_position ASC NULLS LAST]]
       │   Layout: [ordinal_position:bigint, concat:varchar, table_name:varchar]
       │   CPU: 34.00ms (9.39%), Scheduled: 36.00ms (0.18%), Blocked: 0.00ns (0.00%), Output: 1554 rows (142.90kB)
       │   Input avg.: 388.50 rows, Input std.dev.: 34.28%
       └─ RemoteSource[sourceFragmentIds = [3]]
              Layout: [ordinal_position:bigint, concat:varchar, table_name:varchar]
              CPU: 0.00ns (0.00%), Scheduled: 0.00ns (0.00%), Blocked: 1.30m (40.00%), Output: 1554 rows (142.90kB)
              Input avg.: 388.50 rows, Input std.dev.: 34.28%

Fragment 3 [SOURCE]
    CPU: 322.87ms, Scheduled: 19.47s, Blocked 0.00ns (Input: 0.00ns, Output: 0.00ns), Input: 2128 rows (132.89kB), Data Scanned: 132.89kB; per task: avg.: 2128.00 std.dev.: 0.00, Output: 1554 rows (142.90kB)
    Output layout: [ordinal_position, concat, table_name]
    Output partitioning: ROUND_ROBIN []
    ScanFilterProject[table = awsdatacatalog:InformationSchemaTableHandle{catalogName=awsdatacatalog, table=COLUMNS, prefixes=[awsdatacatalog.information_schema.*, awsdatacatalog.dbparquet123.*, awsdatacatalog.dbparquet231004.*, awsdatacatalog.dbparquet456.*, awsdatacatalog.manualcrawlerdbtest1.*, awsdatacatalog.testdatabase.*, awsdatacatalog.testdatabase2.*], limit=OptionalLong.empty}, filterPredicate = ((NOT ("column_name" IN (VARCHAR 'date_created', VARCHAR 't'))) AND "$like"("table_name", "$literal$"(from_base64('DgAAAFZBUklBQkxFX1dJRFRIAQAAAAEAAAAPAAAAAA8AAAAKAAAAJTk1OGQyMjE5JQA=')))), projectLocality = LOCAL]
        Layout: [ordinal_position:bigint, concat:varchar, table_name:varchar]
        CPU: 323.00ms (89.23%), Scheduled: 19.47s (99.79%), Blocked: 0.00ns (0.00%), Output: 1554 rows (142.90kB)
        Input avg.: 2128.00 rows, Input std.dev.: 0.00%
        concat := concat("table_name", VARCHAR '.', "column_name")
        ordinal_position := ordinal_position
        column_name := column_name
        table_name := table_name
        Input: 2128 rows (132.89kB), Filtered: 26.97%, Physical input: 132.89kB, Physical input time: 0.00ns
```

Comment: Can you please do `EXPLAIN ANALYZE {your statement};` and paste the output in the question?

Comment: Updated it now with more details incl. the explain analyze output